# Как получить название проданной опции товара [Ebay API]

Tags: rest

Цель - получать все проданные заказы с Ebay.
Многие товары продаём с опциями.

Получаю список заказов запросом /getOrders

Мне нужно получить название товара и название всех выбранных пользователем опций. Но из полезного в массиве только название товара и id вариаций.

```
[legacyVariationId] => 472816190595
[title] => Great Western Trail + Rails to the North insert (organizer)
```

Пытался также воспользоваться методом GetItem (Trading API). Там есть описание опций, но невозможно понять что именно выбрал пользователь, т.к. legacyVariationId генерируется уникальный для каждого заказа.